# Websockets or HTTP | B2B environment

Tags: http, enterprise-architecture, websockets

Let's start off with the infrastructure architecture that we have, because that's the most important aspect of this conversation.

1. Clients (browsers) which communicate with the product cluster (over WS). Having a websocket connection here makes a lot of sense, because there's a lot of data being exchanged which both is sent from the server to the client and vice versa.
2. Product cluster communicates with another cluster (Proxy cluster) that's within the same data-center. Effectively, proxy cluster manages the environment configuration settings and acts as an adapter between the two services. Between the product cluster and proxy cluster there's also a websocket connection.
3. Proxy cluster communicates with Main server over HTTP. Main server takes care of the main business logic, forwards requests further downstream if necessary, and communicates with database.

We were pitched an idea to migrate from websocket connection to HTTP in step #2 (product cluster & proxy cluster connection), simply because:

- The advantage of having a low latency WS connection is meaningless, since in step #3 there's HTTP connection anyways.
- In reality there's more than one product cluster that connects with the proxy cluster. Actually there's hundreds, and majority of them are already only using HTTP. Moreover, those clusters which connect with HTTP are not in the same data center either.
- Websockets are using different API than HTTP. Supporting both is a headache for the organization.
- There is a need for bidirectional communication, however, this can be easily solved through exposing an endpoint from the server, as is done between proxy cluster and main server.

Those are all solid points, however, i'd like to understand further about the implications on moving from WS to HTTP. Majority of the explanations in the web consider simple one-page apps that deal with instant messaging or pushing updates, but not with large scale operations such as we have.

The biggest pitfall I can see is the increase in latency due to handshake when setting up multiple TCP connections with HTTP as HTTP is not asynchronous like WS is.
What would be the best way to evaluate the potential latency increase? Are there any other ideas that I should take into consideration?

Let's say that product cluster sends about 500 000 commands per hour to the server. What about if this number grows to 1 million, or 10 million?

Comment: I think it should be decided based on what communication style suits your specific use case rather than worrying about latency.
HTTP and Websockets are meant for solving different problems. If communication between the two systems is based on a request-response model and is stateless, HTTP is better suited. Whereas, WebSockets is suited for streaming/real-time models where the client is able to subscribe to the updates from the server for a given request.
Of course, technically you can do streaming with HTTP (long-polling) and request response with websocket, it should be properly justified

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's a mix of both, but the vast majority of the data is sent through request-response model. What i'm worried about is the amount of requests sent and the asynchronousity of the websockets that wouldn't be there with HTTP.